# Remove hyperlink with specific html class PHP

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

i want remove hyperlink with specific html class and keep the text.,

```
$string = 'My content in <a href="http://google.com" class="google">Google</a> not show, but on <a href="http://bing" class="bing">Bing</a> looks good.';
```

I try with this code, but remove all hyperlink. I want only remove hyperlink in "Google".

```
$content = preg_replace( '#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $string );
```

I want, final result like this.,

```
$content = 'My content in Google not show, but on <a href="http://bing" class="bing">Bing</a> looks good.';
```

Please, help. thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?php
  $string = 'My content in <a href="http://google.com" class="google">Google</a> <b><i>not show</i></b>, but on <a href="http://bing" class="bing">Bing</a> looks good.';
    $string=explode(',',$string);
    $newArray=array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($string as $row){
        if (strpos($row, 'google') !== false) {
            $newArray[$i] =strip_tags($row,'<b><i>');
        }
        else{
            $newArray[$i]=$row;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $string= implode ( $newArray );
    echo $string;
```

It removes all the html tags if it finds "google" and keeps the htlm tags for all the rest.

Comment: But the code will remove other HTML tag to, ex: <b></b>

Comment: New edit. It will remove all html tags except the ones that are in the "allowable" section of strip_tags.  Added a new example in $string variable to see it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Using [this test](https://regex101.com/r/zHWFvS/1) I added the word Google in, so that it did not match the Bing link, so your code would now become:

```
$content = preg_replace( '#<a.*?>(.*?)Google</a>#i', 'Google', $string );
```

It now matches the whole link where it contains the text 'Google', and uses the replace function to replace it with just the text.

Comment: No ending delimiter '#' found

Comment: Thanks for answer, Google only example. Exactly Google can change with other words. So, the string is dynamic.

Comment: put your string with php in preg_replace(). so it will become dynamic.

Comment: Can i use strip_tags( $activity_content, '<a class="goolge">' ); ?

Answer (score 0):

I try this code is good for your need:

```
$content = preg_replace( '#<a href=".*?Google.*?".*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $string );
```

and the out put is:

```
My content in Google not show, but on <a href="http://bing" class="bing">Bing</a> looks good.
```

Answer (score 0):

mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] ) (from php.net)

As you can see, you could put a limit on fourth parameter and takes only the first or N($limit)

e.g:(N=1)

$content = preg_replace( '#(.*?)#i', '\1', $string , 1);
//Will take only the first match

e.g:(N=5)

$content = preg_replace( '#(.*?)#i', '\1', $string , 5);
//Will take the first five matchs